# Firebase for Unity Android project - New User Registration - Not Showing in Console

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm registering a new user. I have an email/password/password-confirmation form, they press confirm, and when the credentials are verified to be well-written (each long enough, and password matches confirmation), the email and password is given to the Firebase code that should add a new user.

The code I'm using is listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start) under 'Sign up new users'. Once in game, if I fill out the form properly and it runs the code to add the user, I get the success debugging message 'Firebase user created successfully'. However, as you can see [in this screenshot here](https://i.gyazo.com/34d8fba1d27af5d2b022daca473c48b5.png), in my console there are still no users listed once I've created a user this way. Furthermore, the same credentials can be used to create the same user again, and it still logs that it's succeeding, which I don't think should happen.

What could I be missing or doing wrong here?